# flutter FAILURE: Build failed with an exception https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/?.?.??/groovy-?.?.??.pom

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

When I try to run a Flutter application for the first time, I encounter this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
```

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/?.?.??/groovy-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/?.?.??/groovy-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-ant/?.?.??/groovy-ant-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-ant/?.?.??/groovy-ant-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-astbuilder:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-astbuilder/?.?.??/groovy-astbuilder-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-astbuilder/?.?.??/groovy-astbuilder-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-console:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-console/?.?.??/groovy-console-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-console/?.?.??/groovy-console-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-datetime:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-datetime/?.?.??/groovy-datetime-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-datetime/?.?.??/groovy-datetime-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-dateutil/?.?.??/groovy-dateutil-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-dateutil/?.?.??/groovy-dateutil-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-nio:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-nio/?.?.??/groovy-nio-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-nio/?.?.??/groovy-nio-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-sql/?.?.??/groovy-sql-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-sql/?.?.??/groovy-sql-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-test/?.?.??/groovy-test-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-test/?.?.??/groovy-test-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-templates/?.?.??/groovy-templates-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-templates/?.?.??/groovy-templates-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-json/?.?.??/groovy-json-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-json/?.?.??/groovy-json-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-xml/?.?.??/groovy-xml-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-xml/?.?.??/groovy-xml-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-groovydoc:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-groovydoc/?.?.??/groovy-groovydoc-?.?.??.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-groovydoc/?.?.??/groovy-groovydoc-?.?.??.pom
     Required by:
         project :gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 57s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

this is my gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

my app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.sfesthmp.sfesth"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.sfesthmp.sfesth"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

my android/build.gradel

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have searched through multiple sources before asking here, but I couldn't find a solution to this problem. I turned to you because I know that Stack Overflow is a vast knowledge base unmatched in the world of technology in general. I hope you can help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code at end fo the folloing file **app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'
}
```